# What is the relationship between the short ratio, short interest record date, and short covering?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities, market-data

Assuming if company ABC settle short interest dated on September 8 (does it have to be mid or end of each month for every company to settle short interests or it is only when they have to report?), FINRA will issue record date at Sept 15th? If short ratio is 10 days and SI record date is Sept 15th, does it mean the shorts will need to start covering on Sept 25th?

Answer (score 1):

The short ratio is the number of shares sold short divided by the historical average trading volume. [Source](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/shortinterestratio.asp)

Shorts are generally not required to cover their positions based on a fixed number of days.  Instead, it depends on borrow availability and margin requirements.  A short position can theoretically be open for years.

Comment: Thanks.  Ok, so when the SI settlement date/record date is published, how do I know when these short dates actually took place?

Comment: @ShunChang, you could subtract two reports to calculate the net change over the period.  However, if short interest increased from 1 share to 10, you do not know whether the previous short position is still open or if all 10 shares are a new position.  For example, it could be that the person who was short 1 share is now short 10 or it could be that the first person closed their position and someone else is now short 10 shares.

Comment: what 2 reports are you referring to?  So, the SI report doesn't really help much in this case?  I am trying to gauge when the heavy shorts will tend to cover which triggers the squeeze. thanks again!